# How do I use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Tags: inequality

I wouldn't have posted if I hadn't searched in every site about [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Schwarz_inequality) or bcs or Bunyakovsky inequality. But the only thing I can find is the statement and a proof.

In many answers in this SE I found referrals to CBS. but I cannot understand which vectors I can use to get the result. For example

$$\frac{a^4}{a^2+ab} + \frac{b^4}{b^2 + bc} + \frac{c^4}{c^2 + ac} \ge \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ab + ac + bc}$$

I have also noted that many times the inequality looks like

$$\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{c^2}{d} + \frac{e^2}{f} \ge \frac{(a+c+e)^2}{b+d+f}$$

Is something like this valid? If yes, how can I end with this, using BCS (or any other inequality)?

Comment: The two vectors are $\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{b}}, \frac{c}{\sqrt{d}}, \frac{e}{\sqrt{f}}\right)$ and $(\sqrt{b},\sqrt{d},\sqrt{f})$.

Comment: http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/Books/CSMC/CSMC_index.html is fun and excellent

Answer (score 2):

In case $b+d+f>0$, multiplying $(b+d+f)$ to both sides will give $(\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{c^2}{d}+\frac{e^2}{f})(b+d+f)\geq (a+c+e)^2$, and it is a direct corollary from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.